# Scansion of a Greek line from Babrius 20

Tags: greek, poetry, scansion, metre

In Babrius fable 20 it says:

> θεῶν ἀληθῶς προσεκύνει τε κἀτίμα.

The piece is written in Choliambic style, and I can't figure out how to scan this line.
The problem is that there are two consecutive short syllables on "προσεκύνει", and I don't know where the long syllable should be marked on this word, in a way that does not "ruin" the whole rhyme.
Can someone help me scan this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many Greek meters there's a rule by which a long syllable can be replaced with two shorts ("[resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(meter))"). This is what has happened with προσεκύνει in this line: the first two short syllables count as one long. Dividing the line into feet we get

> θεῶν ἀλη|θῶς προσεκύνει | τε κἀτίμα

where the metrical scheme is

> ˘ ¯ ˘ ¯ | ¯ ˘˘ ˘ ¯ | ˘ ¯ ¯ ¯

The second syllable of the second foot has been "resolved", from ¯ ¯ ˘ ¯ to ¯ ˘˘ ˘ ¯.